# How can a watir script open a file in a different folder?

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble opening a `.txt` file that is in a different set of folders than where I have my .rb test script. I have a file structure of different test categories and then one generic folder that holds data files like `.txt` and Excel files.

Example:

```
Test Scripts -> Data                     This is where the data files are saved
Test Scripts -> Home Page -> Checkout    This is where the .rb test file is
```

I am using this to open the `.txt` file now:

```
File.open("Data/activeSites.txt")
```

when the `.rb` is in the same folder as the `Data` folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you're asking, the issue is that you want to move your Ruby script from `TestScripts/` to `TestScripts/HomePage/Checkout/` and aren't sure how to refer to the `activeSites.txt` file from there.  Is that correct?

If so, you just need to know that `../` means "the parent directory", so you can use:

```
File.open("../../Data/activeSites.txt")
```

The first `../` refers to the Home Page folder, then the second takes you up one more level to the Test Scripts folder.